# Aligning (and cropping) images in HTML so they don't overlap

Tags: html, image, drupal

I'm trying to style a list of content generated by Drupal Views. I can edit the HTML output of fields but have no access to the CSS. The content includes an image which needs floating/aligning to the left so that text flows around it. The original image files are a variety of sizes. The HTML I'm using for the image field is:

```
<img src="[image url]" width="220" height="auto" align="left" />
```

However, in some cases where images are longer than others, I get an overlapping effect like this:

[image]

What I want is for them all to display like this:

[image]
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal provides by default feature of cropping/scaling images. There's no point of providing larger images and scaling them down or cropping them with CSS. That's waste of resources (bandwidth).

Go to Configuration -> Media -> Image styles (from admin menu) and define style you need. It's super easy - you just need to name your style and the pick effect you want (i.e. "Scale & crop"), set dimensions you need and save new style.

Then you should start using that style. If your page is generated by view the find and edit that view. Find that image field and set it to use your new style.

Other way is to force displaying of images in your style from template file directly. Find where image is printed and use:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7

First parameter is style name, so put name of style you just created. Other parameter is URI (not path, as mentioned on that page!). Print out (print_r or var_dump whole image object you have in template file and see how can you access image URI. It should be something like:

```
$node->field_my_image['und'][0]['uri'])
```

So pass that as second parameter.

Comment: OK thanks, it didn't occur to me to define a new image style. I've done that and that has solved the image size problem, but now I can't get the images to left-align with the text. In my original post I was using the image URL and rewriting the output of the field in the view to achieve the "float left" effect. Now I'm using an excluded field displaying the cropped image and rewriting that with <div style="overflow:hidden; text-align:left;">[field_image]</div> but Drupal is ignoring the style declarations so the image is simply appearing by itself on one line and the text directly below.

Comment: Can you change/create template files? If so, then you can put exact html you like and just dynamically print in image paths. Check in firebug or some similar inspector tool what CSS is applied. Since you are writing inline CSS it should have top priority. If you really have no choice you can use "important" qualifier, but, since it's inlice css...I doubt that some other CSS overwrote yours.

Comment: No I have no access to the CSS or the template files unfortunately :(

Answer (score -1):

Even if you don't have access to the CSS you can still use CSS by adding `style` in your HTML tags.

As to your overlapping problems, assuming that you have a `div` that contains your images use can set that `div`'s `style`to `style="overflow:hidden"`. You can also just give enough space to the `div` that contain your image.